# How to fill age with average age according to sex in Titanic data set?

Tags: python, pandas

In the Titanic data set passengers, sex and age are given, but there are some empty values for age. I would like to enter the average by `sex`.

```
    Sex
    female    27.915709
    male      30.726645
```

Where the sex is equal to male I would like to ent the average male age and the same for sex equal to female

I'm somewhat new haven't tried too much

```
titanic.Sex = 'male' and titanic.Age.fillna(mean_homme)
```

The Nan for male  age will equal the average male age

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work.  here is a sample of some new code I'm trying titanic.fillna(titanic.groupby('Sex').Age.mean())

Comment: Nor did this work    
    titanic.Age.fillna(titanic.groupby('Sex')['Age'].mean())

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
df['male']=df['male'].fillna(df['male'].mean())
```